# Cocoapods with framework that is used in different host applications

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies, cocoapods

I have a `Framework` that is included in two different host applications. `pod install` leads to alternating changes to be commited to git. The question is how can i unify the usage, so the `.xcodeproj` file stays stable (no changes) when i do `pod install` in both host applications Here is the project strucutre

## The structure

#### The `Framework`

- This is what all is about
- Its `.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` always has changes if `AppA` did pod install, or `AppB` did pod install. I want this file to **not get any changes anymore after any pod install from the host apps**

#### AppA

- Here is the `Podfile`

```
# Global spec
workspace 'AppA.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

### Import framework_pods
require_relative 'Submodules/Framework/Dependencies'

### Host app pods
target 'AppA' do
  framework_pods
end

### Framework pods
target 'Framework' do
  project 'Submodules/Framework/Framework/Framework.xcodeproj'
  framework_pods
end
```

#### AppB

- Here is the `Podfile`

```
# Global spec
workspace 'AppB.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

### Import framework_pods
require_relative 'Dependencies'

### Host app pods
target 'AppB' do
  project 'AppB/AppB.xcodeproj'
  framework_pods
end

### Framework pods
target 'Framework' do
  project 'Framework/Framework.xcodeproj'
  framework_pods
end
```

#### Sidenotes

- `Framework` and `AppB` live in the same git repo
- `AppA` lives in a separate git repo, but includes it via git submodule
- Here is the content of the `Dependencies.rb` which is inlcuded via `require_relative` in each podfile

```
def framework_pods
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 5.1.0'
  pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 5.1.0'
  pod 'lottie-ios' 
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.11.2' 
end
```

## The problem

Now the thing is each time I execute `pod install` in `AppA`, the `Framework.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` received changes. When i stage them, and then execute `pod install` in `AppB`. Again new changes. And this is never ending. The file never gets stable and can be properly committed to the repo.

**Any ideas on how to fix this situation? Both apps are actively developed and need to import the framework.**

## Limitations

I can't just create a `podspec` for `Framework` as the xcode project contains lots of customizations in the build phases for example. Recreating all of this customizations would be tedious and not maintainable for me.

Answer (score 1):

One way around I can think of, is to

0. Separate Framework from AppB into different folder or repo
1. Create `Framework.podspec` in the Framework folder or repo
2. In that podspec, define the dependencies from Dependencies.rb
3. Delete Dependencies.rb
4. Plug Framework as a development pod to AppB from the local `Framework.podspec` (assuming Framework folder with podspec is next to AppB folder with Podfile):

   ```
   pod Framework, :path => '../Framework'
   ```

If you don’t have local pod specs repo,

5. Plug Framework as a development pod to AppA from the local spec

   ```
   pod Framework, :path => 'Submodules/Framework/Framework'
   ```

If you have local pod specs repo

5. push Framework.podspec there
6. use Framework as regular pod in AppA without the risk of modifying Framework’s original version-controlled sources by AppA developers.

Comment: okay, sounds like a plan. One question. AppB is being used actively to develop and extend Framework. Will this work with this setup? I mean both are already in separate folders in the same repo, but will this support active developmet of Framework inside the AppB workspace?

Comment: You will be able to modify sources of Framework from AppB workspace, however, adding some things which are not yet covered by podspec, might be inconsistent until you do cover it by podspec. You can also mix and match, and keep AppB workspace as it was before (not switching to Framework as a dev pod), and only do that for AppA.

Comment: Okay, and is there any other way, without creating the Framework as a pod with podspec? I just realized there are tons of build phase scripts and project customizations. So reflecting all of this in a podfile is tedious.. any other way?

Comment: Would this be possible with different targets?

Comment: Another way is to ship Framework for AppA as prebuilt framework. Then you won't need the Framework's build phase scripts in AppA. The other way is to use BUCK.build and Podfiles with `:integrate_targets => false`. In that way you won't have `.xcodeproj` files being pushed into git.